# MySQL query to find the most popular value in a column joined by another value in a second table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

- **users**: user_id, user_zip
- **settings**: user_id, pref_ex_loc

I need to find the single most popular 'pref_ex_loc' from the settings table based on a particular user_zip, which will be specified as the variable $userzip.

Here is the query that I have now and obviously it doesn't work.

```
$popularexloc = "SELECT pref_ex_loc, user_id COUNT(pref_ex_loc) AS countloc 
       FROM settings FULL OUTER JOIN users ON settings.user_id = users.user_id 
       WHERE users.user_zip='$userzip' 
       GROUP BY settings.pref_ex_loc 
       ORDER BY countloc LIMIT 1";

$popexloc = mysql_query($popularexloc) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
$exlocrow = mysql_fetch_array($popexloc); 
$mostpopexloc=$exlocrow[0];
echo '<option value="'.$mostpopexloc.'">'.$mostpopexloc.'</option>';
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm not getting any kind of error from this either.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing you are missing a comma before the COUNT():

```
SELECT pref_ex_loc, user_id COUNT(...
```

You should have a comma between each field in your select-list:

```
SELECT pref_ex_loc, user_id, COUNT(...
```

I would recommend using `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(pref_ex_loc)`.  In this case, either should give the right answer, but in MySQL `COUNT(*)` usually performs slightly better.

You're using outer join, but then in the WHERE clause you're testing one of the columns of `users` so it's effectively not an outer join anymore.  In this query, I believe you simply need an INNER JOIN, unless you need to handle the possibility that none of the users reference *any* of your pref_ex_loc values.  Read [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Also, MySQL [does not support FULL OUTER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html).

Your `user_id` in the select-list, when it is neither in the GROUP BY clause nor in an aggregate function, is an ambiguous field, taking its value from one arbitrary row in the group.  You should remove `user_id` from the select-list.

Sort by the countloc `DESC` to get the greatest value first.

So here's what I see as a better query:

```
SELECT pref_ex_loc, COUNT(*) AS countloc 
FROM settings INNER JOIN users ON settings.user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE users.user_zip='$userzip' GROUP BY settings.pref_ex_loc 
ORDER BY countloc DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: comma thing is same in your answer and question could you please clarify

Comment: I failed to include a comma after the second column in the query associated with my question.

Comment: Thank you for all the great information!  Your query works perfectly as well as Mosty Mostacho's.  I'm glad I asked this question because it's really helping me understand the concept of JOIN.  It's a difficult concept to grasp, but the tutorial you linked is a great way to visualize it.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
select s.pref_ex_loc from settings s
join users u on (u.user_id = s.user_id)
where user_zip = $userzip
group by s.pref_ex_loc
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

As you said, this will give you the "single most popular 'pref_ex_loc' from the settings table based on a particular user_zip"

Comment: Perfect.  That makes perfect sense.  Actually I tried to use JOIN first, but when I couldn't get it to work I thought maybe I should be using a different JOIN.  I had the right concept, just not the right query to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

this will allow values (*duplicate most popular*) with the highest `pref_ex_loc` to be shown in the list.

It doesn't use `LIMIT`, because `LIMIT` forces the maximum number of rows to be shown. Now, here's the question, **What if there are two or more rows that ties up with the most popular pref_ex_loc?**

```
SELECT  b.pref_ex_loc
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN settings b
            ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID
WHERE   a.user_zip = 1  -- change the value here
GROUP BY    b.pref_ex_loc
HAVING COUNT(*) =
(
  SELECT MAX(totalCount)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT  b.pref_ex_loc, COUNT(*) totalCount
    FROM    users a
            INNER JOIN settings b
                ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID
    WHERE   a.user_zip = 1  -- change the value here
    GROUP BY    b.pref_ex_loc
  ) s
)
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86a7b/1)
- [**SQLFiddle Demo** (*with duplicate most popular*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b959d/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(pref_ex_loc) AS countloc
FROM users LEFT JOIN settings ON users.user_id = settings.user_id
WHERE users.user_zip='$userzip' GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY countloc LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This returns the user with the most settings, not the setting with the most users.